# Maven: jars from zipped artifact as test dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, classpath

I have a project A that depends on a distribution of another project B. The distribution is a zip file which contains some resources and jars. It is contained as a .zip artifact in a maven repository.
I do not need the distribution of project B for compilation but for running tests for project A.

I use the dependency-plugin and the goal dependency:unpack to download and unzip the distribution. 
1. Is there a possibility to get all .jar files contained in the .zip distribution in the classpath for the surefire plugin without naming every single jar explicitely?
2. If possible I also would like to include those jar files in the classpath of a eclipse project generated by the eclipse-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the classpath of the surefire plugin right?  And of your eclipse project?

If so, you can use the maven plugin as shown [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) and filter to only copy jars and use the output directory that you configured in your classpath.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi Carlos,
thanks for your answer. I think i did not describe my problem properly.

The distribution contains >20 jars with different versions. I only really care for the version of the distribution. Unpacking is not an issue, but I want to automatically add all the jars that were unpacked to the classpath of surefire and the eclipse project.

Comment: Store your version in a variable and use that in the filter for the unpack plugin. Set the output directory of the unpack plugin to something in your classpath.